# What is the purpose of adding profile to changeset

Tags: profile, change-set

I developed a few automated flows and when creating the changeset, there is an option to add profiles. I went through the salesforce documentation, but could not find out the exact use case of adding profiles. Like how would a profile relate to a component that is in the changeset?

Answer (score 1):

If you add profiles to the changeset then all the access rights defined in the profile will be enabled in the destination org. This access rights could be object level access, FLS, recordtype, page layout assignment etc.

If you do not add profiles in the changeset then after deployment you need to provide those access rights explicitly to those profiles.

Comment: If I haven't changed any permissions, then I don't need to add profiles in my changeset right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

@I am just extending satanu boral answer for your understanding

You have not changed any permission in profile,then you no need to do any thing

Just explaining the answer considering apex class  and visualforce page.

If you created new apex classes,visual force pages. now you are pushing that changes to production.

Suppose you haven't added profiles in change set,then you have to perform that steps in production as a post deployment activity.

If you have pushed apex class ,visualforce page etc along with profile then you no need to perform that operation,you can save the time in Production.

Comment: Okay, so If I have added an apex class, do I need to add the class to the profiles before creating the changeset?

Comment: in simple words. if you  added  profile in changeset and your are pushing apex class along with that automatically  class and its profile permission will appear in production. otherwise you need to add it manually...you need to go each apex class then you need to add the profile for that...

Comment: you can save the time. suppose if you have strict dead line for completing the post deployment activity..its really difficult right. thats why if you push the changes along with that profile.it will be the advantage